# need multiple occurances from solr highlighting instead of only the 1st occurance

Tags: solr, highlighting

I have seen documents on solr highlighting and i found that i need to change the default value of snippet. I have given value at 20 and made the maxAnalyzedChars 999999 from schema.xml. even then i get only the first occurance.

I have also added some part in solrconfig.xml also

```
<requentestHandler name="/search"  class="solr.SearchHandler"> 
<lst name="defaults"> 
 <str name="defType">dismax</str> 
 <int name="rows">10</int> 
 <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
 <str name="qf">content&#94;0.5 title&#94;1.2 </str> 
 <str name="q.alt">*:*</str> 
 <bool name="hl">true</bool> 
 <str name="hl.fl">title content url</str> 
 <str name="f.content.hl.fragsize">20</str> 
 <str name="f.content.hl.snippets">3</str>  
 <str name="f.content.hl.alternateField">content</str> 
 <str name="f.title.hl.fragsize">0</str> 
 <str name="f.title.hl.alternateField">title</str> 
 <str name="f.url.hl.fragsize">0</str> 
 <str name="f.url.hl.alternateField">url</str> 
</lst>
```

Can anyone pls help me out? I am new to Solr. My requirment is to fetch the phrases containing a given word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Solr Highlighting to find the multiple occurrences of searched text. Solr gives only one occurrence by default. I tried with `/select` request handler. While querying I passed the following parameters.

```
hl.fragsize=999999999&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=999999999
```

Now, it's able to find the multiple occurrences of the searched text. I hope these parameters will also work for your `/search` handler. So, try to provide a very large number for **hl.fragsize** and **hl.maxAnalyzedChars**.

Comment: It did. But I get the entire content of the file. I wanted to display just line having the searched text. For example if STACKOVERFOLW is present 4 times in a large document, I need only those 4 lines having STACKOVERFOLW.

Please do help

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [hl.snippets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.snippets) param to specify the number of snippets you want.

[Edit] - Regarding your comments, it seems that you were querying the wrong requestHandler. Well, that might explain your problem, then. Anyway, here are some clarifications that might be useful :

- [`hl.snippets`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.snippets) corresponds to the **maximum** number of snippets to be returned. Use it as a limit.
- [`hl.fragsize`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize) corresponds to the length of the string you want to be returned from the matched field (snippets length). A value of "`0`" means unlimited length or whole field.

When hl.fragsize is set to a value greater than a field's content length, the highlighter can return only one single snippet from that field (the entire field), regardless of hl.snippets value or the number of match in that field.

To obtain the phrase that contains highlighting as a snippet, use a fragsize equivalent to what you consider as an average phrase length (100~300 are commonly used values).

Comment: I havce set it to 20. But still only one occurance i used to get. And if i follow the above method, I get the whole file content and get <em> aroung the searched text. I just need the phrase containing the searched text. not the whole content